# Create a Case Sensitive Login Form in VB 10

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to Create a Login Form that the fields in password are case sensitive example if my passwords is "PassWord" it will only accepts the keyword "PassWord" and not accepts "password" Or "PASSWORD" keyword etc. I want it a character sensitive thanks Please Help me Im a new Programmer using DATABASE MS ACCESS Thanks Here is my code

```
 Private Sub btnLog_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLog.Click
    Try
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\NIASecurity.accdb")
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Username] FROM [Security] WHERE [Username] = @User and Password =@Pass ", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", txtUser.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", txtPass.Text)
        con.Open()
        Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If sdr.Read Then
            If txtPass.Text = sdr(0) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome")
                Dim win As New frmAdd
                win.MdiParent = frmMDI
                win.Show()
                Me.Close()
            Else
                MsgBox("Invalid name or password!")

            End If
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid name or password!")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please please please don't store your password in plain text. Use password hashing (bcrypt, PBKDF2,...) In the case of a database compromise, your users shouldn't worry about changing their password somewhere else.

Comment: HOw to do that? please?

Answer (score 0):

I can say you for save passwords in db, you must save password Data with Hashing `Algorithm` such as `MD5` or `SHA1`
When user type password for login you hash string that typed for password and compare this string with password that save in db

```
    public static void HashPassword(string Password, out string Salt, out string Hash)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        byte[] s = new byte[20];
        rnd.NextBytes(s);
        Salt = Convert.ToBase64String(s);
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding u = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] pass = u.GetBytes(Password);
        byte[] all = new byte[pass.Length + s.Length];
        Array.Copy(pass, all, pass.Length);
        Array.Copy(s, 0, all, pass.Length, s.Length);
        Byte[] H = sha.ComputeHash(all);
        Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(H);
    }

    public bool IsPasswordCorrect(string Password, string Salt, string Hash)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed();
        byte[] s = Convert.FromBase64String(Salt);
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding u = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] pass = u.GetBytes(Password);
        byte[] all = new byte[pass.Length + s.Length];
        Array.Copy(pass, all, pass.Length);
        Array.Copy(s, 0, all, pass.Length, s.Length);
        Byte[] H = sha.ComputeHash(all);
        return (Hash == Convert.ToBase64String(H));
    }
```

now you must use `HashPassword` method to give hash an salt and  save hash and salt to db for every user.
When want to check password use `IsPasswordcorrect` Method

Comment: I can send you an example

Comment: Can you revised my code im not familiar with that code you've given to me thank you so much or where can i put that line of code in my code thanks again more power newbie here

Comment: I'm Using VISUAL BASIC 2010

Comment: You should'nt use MD5 or SHA1, use something that was made for password hashing. See SHA512, PBKDF2,...

Comment: i dont know the SHA512 PBKDF2

Comment: my code in C# but I can change it to vb and send you sample

Comment: i posted  my code in my question what sample did you mean thank you